# Using class compositioning in EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constructor, switch-statement, composition

I am attempting to use class compositioning to circumvent the problem of not being able to inherit from my DB-first generated class named "Item". 
    namespace Conquest
    {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public partial class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Movement { get; set; }
    public Conquest.Players.Items.ItemType Type { get; set; }
    public int VaultId { get; set; }

    public virtual Vault Vault { get; set; }
}
}
```

So instead of creating Item classes by inheriting from the Item base class i.e. `BagOfHolding : Item` I have reworked those child classes to have a `BagOfHolding : ItemLogic`  and then extending the generated partial Item class with an ItemLogic property.

```
public partial class Item
{
    private ItemLogic Logic { get; set; }

    public Item(ItemType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ItemType.AnimalAmulet:
                Logic = new AnimalAmulet();
                break;
            case ItemType.AxeOfDespair:
                Logic = new AxeOfDespair();
                break;
            case ItemType.BagOfHolding:
                Logic = new BagOfHolding();
                break;
            case ItemType.BagOfTricks:
                Logic = new BagOfTricks;
                break;
            case ItemType.BuildersTools:
                Logic = new BuildersTools();
                break;


        }
        this.Name = Logic.Name;
        this.Movement = Logic.Movement;
        this.Type = Logic.Type;
    }
```

As you can see *my constructor is using a switch statement that isn't even complete and just feels dirty and very redundant*, so my question is: **Is there a cleaner way to do this?** My ItemType enum value names are exactly the same as the name of the ItemLogic derived classes they represent and with my current approach any future additions I may make in the way of types of items will be very frustrating.